# Make a flexbox child div 50% width and grow to 100% on wrap

Tags: html, css

I have the following

```
<div style="max-width:100%;flex-wrap:wrap;display:flex">
   <div style="width:50%;flex-grow:1"></div>
   <div style="width:50%;flex-grow:1"></div>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is to have the two child elements start off at 50% width.  When the window size is reduced, I want the second one to wrap below the first one and both of them to grow to 100%.  Right now the first one is starting of at 100%.  I'm using Chrome.

Comment: Before trying any answer make sure you close the inner divs

Comment: @David Daza, I updated the question.  This was just a simplified version of my real code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Forcing the items to `width:50%` is redundant since you would be using `flex`, which can split the width equally if the `flex-grow` is equal for both items and `flex-basis` is set to 0. To get the effect of wrapping "at certain point" you can either use @jake's approach, or define a `min-width` for the elements, after which the wrap will occur naturally. [Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JeapeX) is an example in action.

Answer (score 7):

Adding `@media` would work or you can also check out [this article](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design) on responsive design for flex

```css
.parent{
  background: tomato;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;  
}
.parent > div {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  }
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
  .parent > div{   
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div style="background: yellow"></div>
  <div style="background: green"></div>
</div>
```